# Pandas Series Shift and Conditions return the truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: pandas, iteration, conditional-statements, series, shift

I have a pandas Series `df` containing 10 values (all doubles).
My aim is to create a new Series as follow.

```
   newSerie = 1 if df > df.shift(1) else 0
```

In other words `newSerie` outputs 1 if the current value of `df` is bigger than its previous value (it should output 0 otherwise).

However, I get :

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

In addition after my aim is to concatenate `df` and `newSerie` as a Dataframe, but `newSerie` outputs 9 value as we cannot compare the first value of `df` with shitf(1). Hence I need the first value of `newSerie` to be a empty value in order to be able to concatenate.

How can I do that?

To give an example imagine my input is only Series df. And my output should be as in the following image:

[image]

Comment: What is the name of your dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shift` or `diff`:

```
# example dataframe:
data = pd.DataFrame({'df':[10,9,12,13,14,15,18,16,20,1]})

   df
0  10
1   9
2  12
3  13
4  14
5  15
6  18
7  16
8  20
9   1
```

Using `Series.shift`:

```
data['NewSerie'] = data['df'].gt(data['df'].shift()).astype(int)
```

Or `Series.diff`

```
data['NewSerie'] = data['df'].diff().gt(0).astype(int)
```

**Output**

```
   df  NewSerie
0  10         0
1   9         0
2  12         1
3  13         1
4  14         1
5  15         1
6  18         1
7  16         0
8  20         1
9   1         0
```